# Why is my key not getting pushed inside the array

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [{
   key: "key1", value: "z"
}, {
   key: "key2", value: "u"
}, {
   ...
}];

var sorted = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.key === b.key ? 0
        : a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1;
});

sorted.unshift({key:"Unknown", value:"0"});

var StateArr = [];
 for(i=0;i<sorted.length;i++){
     StateArr.push(sorted[i].key);
}

alert("ARR" +StateArr);
```

Now when i alert my sorted, i don't get any response. Why is my key not getting pushed inside the array.

Comment: Seems ok to me http://jsbin.com/acoles/edit#javascript,html,live  What's it not doing that you expect?

Comment: Try removing `...` and surrounding braces.

Comment: Might want to try to access the array instead of just calling its pointer...`alert("ARR" + StateArr[0].key);`

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine (and "as expected" for me).

What do you receive and what are you expect?